# Import body field into a matrix text block

Tags: matrix, plugins, database, import

I'm working on importing a database and I was looking at some of the available import plugins. However I am unable to figure out how to import a body field (just a string) into a Matrix block.

#### Old database entry structure (non-Crafty)

- title
- description
- body

#### New database entry structure (Crafty)

- title
- description
- matrix [body, image, gallery, etc]

Does anyone have experience with this? Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind. [Clearbold's Craft Import](https://github.com/clearbold/craftimport) plugin has the starting code for it.

```php
// new entry
$entry = new EntryModel();
$entry->sectionId = 1;
$entry->typeId    = 12;
$entry->authorId  = 123;
$entry->enabled   = true;
$entry->getContent()->title = "Here goes my title!";

// new matrix and matrix block
$block = array();
$block['new1'] = array(
    'type' => 'body',
    'enabled' => true,
    'fields' => array(
        'text' => 'Here goes my article.'
    )
);

// add content to entry including created matrix
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'description' => "And of course the description...",
    'matriz' => $block,
));

// save entry
$success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```